# unable to stream rtmp to web page

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, rtmp

I am trying to stream a video in my local drive to the browser using RTMP.
I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/andreanobile/opencv_ffmpeg_streaming).

This is the part of the cpp code:

```
std::string video_fname;
video_fname = std::string(argv[1]);
cv::VideoCapture video_capture;
bool from_camera = false;
if(video_fname == "0") {
    video_capture = cv::VideoCapture(0);
    from_camera = true;
} else {
    video_capture=  cv::VideoCapture(video_fname);
}

if(!video_capture.isOpened()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not open video %s\n", video_fname.c_str());
    video_capture.release();
    return 1;
}

int cap_frame_width = video_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int cap_frame_height = video_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

int cap_fps = video_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
printf("video info w = %d, h = %d, fps = %d\n", cap_frame_width, cap_frame_height, cap_fps);

int stream_fps = cap_fps;

int bitrate = 500000;
Streamer streamer;
StreamerConfig streamer_config(cap_frame_width, cap_frame_height,
                               1920, 1080,
                               stream_fps, bitrate, "high444", "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream");

streamer.enable_av_debug_log();
streamer.init(streamer_config);

size_t streamed_frames = 0;
```

So as you can see the RTMP link is `rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream`, after starting my Nginx, I can simply insert this link into the URL field in my browser and play it without any problem. 
However, now I need to stream it on an HTML web page instead and I couldn't do so.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>videojs-contrib-hls embed</title>

  <!--

  Uses the latest versions of video.js and videojs-http-streaming.

  To use specific versions, please change the URLs to the form:

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js@6.7.1/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js@6.7.1/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming@0.9.0/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

  -->

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Video.js Example Embed</h1>

  <video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream" type="rtmp/flv">
  </video-js>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

  <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting an error saying that the video format is not supported. Please show how to do it. I have gone through all the guides online (they are all the same actually) and none of them work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I keep getting an error saying that the video format is not supported

This is because rtmp is not supported. No browser supports rtmp. You must convert server side to something that is supported, like HLS, or DASH.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  yes, I know that. So the question is how to do it? I saw a lot tutorials online on how to use the videoJS to achieve this, but none of them work for me. 
For the tutorials online, all of them have video sources with ending "m3u8" and I not sure how to get similar source since mine is not the same.
**I chose videoJS because it is free. I need something free
Thanks

Comment: We can only help by answering the questions you ask. You asked why you cant play an rtmp stream in the browser. If you want to know how to convert rtmp to hls, please and ask that question (but first search, because that is answered at least a dozen times here). Please don’t make the people trying to help you jump through hoops.  Its a wast of everybody’s (including your) time.